# Is it possible to create a savable or printable (PDF, Word or other) form in JavaFX by coding?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, pdf-generation

Am in an attempt to make a savable (printable actually) form in JavaFX, that is, it can be saved in the computer as PDF or some other printable format. I searched in google and found many links. Also I found a question in Stack Overflow - [How to generate printable (and savable) forms with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400493/how-to-generate-printable-and-savable-forms-with-java)

I found JasperReports, iText and Docmosis from the above link. I can't make a desired form using these.So is it possible to generate a PDF file by coding in JavaFX ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Apache's [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org).  I am using that to read PDF's with great success, though I haven't worked with any of the writing operations. Tutorials [here](http://www.printmyfolders.com/Home/PDFBox-Tutorial) and [here](https://pdfbox.apache.org/cookbook/documentcreation.html). I primarily used their documentation, found [here](http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.4/javadocs/).

Reading from PDF's is fairly straightforward once you take a look at the documentation, but here's how I use it:

```
//PDFBox API doesn't include generics for PDAcroForm.getFields();
//type-cast should always be safe
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<PDField> fields = form.getFields();
String v;
for (PDField field : fields)
{
    v = field.getValue();
    values.put(field.getFullyQualifiedName(), v == null ? "" : v);
}
```

The inverse operation, saving to a PDF, should likewise be fairly straightforward: `field.setValue(String value)`. Again, I haven't tried to save any PDF's.

Another thing to note: it helps to develop the PDF form yourself, or coordinate with the person who made it (assuming you rely on my method of mapping values by their fully qualified names). If you attempt to persist data that is dependent on the FQN, and it gets changed in the PDF itself, you can have problems.

Comment: Can you provide me some tutorials ?

Comment: Try some simple examples [here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/).

Comment: I updated my answer to include links to tutorials and the documentation.

Comment: I also added a short example to get you started. I had to start from the documentation and slowly put things together one step at a time.

Comment: Is it possible to link NetBeans and PDFBox through any means ?

Comment: @CAGGonzo I downloaded PDFBox from the link you gave. I downloaded a jar file and a zip file. I tried to open the jar file by double clicking. But nothing happened. So how can I use PDFBox ?

Comment: @brian Hey Brian, can you suggest me some other ways to make PDF files.? PDFBox was good, but I am developing my application in NetBeans IDE. So I need something that can be used with NetBeans.

Comment: It works in Netbeans.  It's probably easiest to use Maven.  http://pdfbox.apache.org/dependencies.html  .  If you want help setting up a project that uses dependencies, ask another question.

Comment: @Tom, you don't run the JAR; you add it to your project's build path. That varies based on what IDE you use and what build tool you use (I.e. ant, maven, etc.). Once that is done, you can start with the code in my answer, fix imports, and have at it. Also, I use NetBeans, and it works great.

Comment: @CAGGonzo My IDE is NetBeans and build tool is maven. So how to make link between NetBeans PDFBox ?

Comment: @Tom, the link above by brian is what you want to read. But in NetBeans, you can right click on your Dependencies folder, select Add Dependency, and search for PDFBox. Use the link from brian to confirm you have the right IDs and whatnot.